# Version agnostic way to convert from Java to Scala collections and back

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop, scala-2.11, scala-2.12, scala-2.13

Almost each Scala version changes the way collection conversion happens in a non-backward compatible way. Is there a better solution that is version agnostic and does not depend on Scala distribution?

I don't mind using some 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [*scala-collections-compat* library](https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-compat) and then you can use `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` on **Scala** `2.11`, `2.12` & `2.13`.